# C++ compiler does not warn about missing argument before end of default arguments

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, default-arguments

I declared a C++ function declaration with 3 arguments, two of which had defaults like so.

```
void func(int const n, bool const flag=true, int *array=NULL) {
  /* print contents of array */
}
```

When I invoked the function erroneously, omitting the second argument but including the third argument, like so

```
int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
func(5,array);
```

neither gcc nor intel compilers (default ones on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) complained that the last argument was specified without specifying the second last one. The code ran but sent in NULL for array (I expected the code to fail).

My question is why didn't the compilers complain that it could not find a matching function since the signature of my invocation should have appeared as

```
funct(int const, int *)
```

What options can I turn on during compiling to trigger a warning about this erroneous usage?

Comment: You should enable the "code reviewer yells at you for adding default arguments" warning :)

Comment: There's no warning that I know of. Array->pointer->bool is a perfectly well-defined conversion sequence.

Comment: This is a highly simplified but representative example constructed from a much more complex code where if I avoided arguments with default values, I would have so many overloaded functions for all the variants that it would be quite unwieldy.

Comment: Is there any mechanism  to prevent an argument from undergoing implicit conversion. I am planning on using the method suggested by @Slava (i.e. to switch the order of arguments) but in the context of my larger code it would be semantically much clearer and cleaner, if I could keep the bool arguments with defaults before the pointer arguments with defaults and protect the pointer arguments from explicit conversion.

Answer (score 14):

The compiler decays the array to a pointer and converts the pointer to a `bool` and proceeds.

**Update**

From the C++11 Standard:

> **4 Standard conversions** [conv]
>
> 1 Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such
>   conversions. *A standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion,
>   and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to
>   member conversions, and boolean conversions.
>
> — Zero or one qualification conversion.
>
> [ *Note:* A standard conversion sequence can be empty, i.e., it can consist of no conversions. *—end note* ]
>
> A standard conversion sequence will be applied to an expression if necessary to convert it to a required destination type.

Comment: This is why default arguments are so horrifying.

Comment: Is there 2 conversions array -> ponter -> bool ?

Comment: @Slava, that's my understanding.

Comment: @Slava: an array decays to a pointer so I'm not sure if that's consider that a conversion per se.  Then the pointer can be converted to a bool.

Comment: That. The array is always considered as a pointer so there is indeed only one conversion pointer -> bool involved.

Comment: @maxywb no, it's not.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Yes, array-to-pointer is a conversion per the standard. It's called, unimaginatively, an array-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: @maxywb that is why pointer to bool conversions are so horrifying. Nothing wrong with default arguments per se.

Comment: @haavee, Arrays are not always considered pointers. The decay must happen, as stated.

Comment: @haavee: An array is never "considered" as a pointer. There is an implicit conversion from an array expression to a pointer (to the array's first element). That conversion happens in most, but not all, contexts. (If arrays were pointers, the conversion would not be necessary.)

Comment: @RSahu then 2 implicit conversions should not happen, am I wrong?

Comment: According to what I just learned it depends on the context where the array is used. There are, indeed, I just learned, situations where the conversion is not automatic.

Comment: @Slava, any number of standard conversions can be applied. See the updated answer.

Comment: @rubenvb I just happen to disagree with you. I hate default arguments for more reasons than should be explained in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case solution could be using different argument order:

```
void func(int const n, int *array=NULL, bool const flag=true ) {
  /* print contents of array */
}
```

If you ommit second parameter boolean value cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer (unless you have bad habbit of using 0 as `false`), so it will fail to compile (or at least provide warning).

```
void func(int const n, int *array = nullptr, bool const flag=true ) {
      /* print contents of array */
}

int main()
{
    func( 0, false );
}
```

> warning: converting 'false' to pointer type for argument 2 of 'void
>   func(int, int*, bool)' [-Wconversion-null]

But in general it shows that you should use different technique. For example using `std::vector` instead of raw pointer.

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_vec;
void func( bool const flag=true, const int_vec &array = int_vec() ) {
      /* print contents of array */
}

int main()
{
    int_vec array {1,2,3,4,5};
    func( array );
}
```

> error: cannot convert 'int_vec {aka std::vector}' to 'bool' for
>   argument '1' to 'void func( bool, int_vec)'

Comment: If using 0 as a null pointer, you can at least get GCC to warn you that you should use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard (4 Standard conversions)

> 1 Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning.
>   Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A standard
>   conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the
>   following order:
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set:
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, **array-to-pointer conversion**, and
>   function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral
>   promotions, floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating
>   point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions,
>   pointer to member conversions, and **boolean conversions**.
>
> — Zero or one qualification conversion.

And

4.12 Boolean conversions

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer**, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true. For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

So this function call

```
func(5,array);
```

is equivalent to

```
func(5,array, NULL);
```

the second argument at first was converted from array to pointer (array-to-pointer conversion) and then was converted to boolean true (boolean conversions).

Thus this call is a valid call of the function. The compiler implicitly converts arguments to appropriate types.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit casting to bool taking place.
With Visual C++ you would get a [C4800](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx) warning.
In gcc you can request specific warnings with options beginning with ‘-W’, for example `-Wimplicit` to request warnings on implicit declarations. See [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for the full documentation.